# Maximal Ideal and its relationship with the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I understand that if $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $I+xR =R$ $\forall x \notin I$, but I fail to grasp how the converse can be true. Would anyone be so kind as to offer me a proof/ some hints at how the proof can be done?

Comment: That is not true if $x \in I$ !

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘the converse’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is obviously true. Since if $I$ satisfies the condition then $I$ cannot be contained in any proper ideal $J$ of $R$ because if $x\in J\setminus I$ then $R=Rx +I\subseteq J+I\subseteq J+J =J$.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the obvious idea.

Comment: @rschwieb While this is the answer, I disagree that it is “obviously true” — it was certainly not obvious to the OP.

Comment: +1 This is the very obvious idea, and I agree that it is obviously true.

Comment: @SantanaAfton If you happened to assign a downvote for that reason, I'd just urge you to reconsider, since the sentiment (although you disagree with it) does not affect the correctness, quality or usefulness of the answer.  Downvotes simply because one "does not like the way someone says something" are not very helpful to the community.  Although, it would be completely natural to leave a comment opining that the answer would be better without the "obviously." :)

Comment: @rschwieb I voted not because I don’t *like* the “obvious” sentiment, but because I find such answers as less useful and of lower quality. That said, I see your point. Were the answer edited, I would certainly revoke my downvote and keep my comment up.

Comment: @SantanaAfton OK, it got some edits.